# Move dropzone preview template before uploading

Tags: jquery

I use dropzone for upload files. But I want to know is there possible to group the preview template before uploading process success? Now I only know to move "file.previewElement" after file uploaded. But the problem is, when upload in progress, the file is out from the box because the file is not moving yet. This is my code on success:

```
success : function (file, data) {
        var type = file.type.split('/');
        var fileType = checkFileType(file.name);

        if(type[0] === 'image'){ //if filetype image move to image div
              $('#fieldFile').find('.file-upload-image').prepend(file.previewElement);                      
        }else{ //if others move to document div
             $('#fieldFile').find('.file-upload-document').prepend(file.previewElement);
        }                      
 }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dropzoneoption.init = function () { 
     this.on('addedfile', function (file) { 
       var type = file.type.split('/'); 
       var fileType = checkFileType(file.name);
       if(type[0] === 'image'){ 
         //if filetype image move to image div 
         $('#fieldFile').find('.file-upload-image').prepend(file.previewElement); 
       }else{
          //if others move to document div 
           $('#fieldFile').find('.file-upload-document').prepend(file.previewElement);
     } 
 });
} 
var uploader = $(sheetUploadContainer).dropzone(dropzoneoption);
```